# GNU Linker and architecture i386

Tags: c, macos, assembly, ld, i386

**So I'm running on OS X** and I want to link two Mach-O objects i386.

The first is generated from NASM (it's an assembly file)

```
nasm -f macho -o kernel.o kernel.asm
```

The second is generated from GCC

```
gcc -c -arch i386 screen.c
```

But when I try to link them...

```
ld -o myprogram screen.o kernel.o
```

...I get this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "print", referenced from:
      start in kernel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture i386
```

I don't understand why, because my two files are `Mach-O object i386` :

```
$ file screen.o
screen.o: Mach-O object i386
$ file kernel.o
kernel.o: Mach-O object i386
```

---

If you need it, here's **kernel.asm** :

```
[BITS 32]
EXTERN print
GLOBAL start

start:
    mov  eax, msg
    push eax
    call print
    pop  eax

end:
    jmp end

msg  db 'Hello world!', 10, 0
```

And here's **screen.c** :

```
void putcar(uchar c)
{
    /* Some code here */
}

void print(char *string)
{
        while(*string != 0){
                putcar(*string);
                string++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Were you never curious digging in a binary file before? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the symbol `_print` in your asm file, i.e.

```
start:
    mov  eax, msg
    push eax
    call _print
    pop  eax
```

This is because C function names get a leading underscore when compiled.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Just a little question : how can I convert the 'ld' output to binary ?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary" ? It's already a binary executable. Do you want the binary in human-readable format or something ?

Comment: Before I had the need to link two files, I was just doing that : `nasm -f bin -o kernel kernel.asm` and I was catenating the output with a `x86 boot sector`, but now the output is an `Mach-O executable i386` file...

Comment: OK - it's still not really clear what you're trying to achieve - maybe you should post a separate question with a little more detail as this is really a different problem than your original question.

Comment: `-oformat binary` (if Macho ld works like Linux ld... which it might not). You may need to specify an "origin" with `-T text=0x7D00` (or wherever your bootsector loads it).  I think "objcopy" will do it, too(?). http://www.osdev.org may know something about this...